# WSO2 API Manager - is ESB and rest of Carbon framework included in this package?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am trying to build a POC using WSO2 middle ware that demonstrates API Management as well as ESB features. Will I need to download WSO2 Carbon as well as WSO2 API Manager? Or does WSO2 API Manager include ESB and the rest of the Carbon framework?

Answer (score 1):

The API Manager is based on Carbon, and contains the features it needs to provide the advertised functionality. In other words, out of the box, you get API management, the API gateway, the API store and the publisher apps. If you need full ESB features beyond what the API gateway functionality provides, you can download the ESB separately. 
Isabelle.